# Автоматическая отправка email

Tags: java, android, sendmail

Мне нужно ПОЛНОСТЬЮ автоматическая отправка письма на email. Очень распространённый код ниже прекрасен: он заполняет поля письма и автоматически выбирает программу отправки, но критически не хватает последнего пинка - автоматического "нажатия" на кнопку отправки.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "andron.gen@gmail.com"));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My email subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My email body");

        try {startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Что нужно дописать/исправить, что бы оно само пошло гулять?

Comment: 1 вариант: Юзай JavaMail API. 2 вариант: Если есть сервер, напиши скрипт, который будет слать mail, а в приложении дергай его

Answer (score 1):

Средствами андроид вы этого сделать не сможете т.к. система запрещает вам делать какие-либо действия без ведома пользователя.

Если вы хотите отправлять email как вы хотите, вам необходимо написать полностью свой сервис по отправке почты и взаимодействовать с ним из вашего приложения.

Comment: Я понял, что это очень сложно для начинающего, по этому сразу капитулируюсь без жертв). Это большая помощь, Спасибо!

Comment: @AndreiAndreiPedash Ничего сложного. Вот пример, где все доступно объяснено как решить вашу проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a